# SQL Update conflict with Check constraint error

Tags: sql, dml

I'm trying to update some numeric values in stored procedure

```
SET SubTotal = SubTotal + @ExtCost
                , GST = SubTotal * 0.05
                , Total = SubTotal + GST
            WHERE JobNumber = @JobNumber
```

`@ExtCost` and `@JobNumber` are all valid and work fine.

I get this error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ck_SubTotalandTotal"

The check constraint is `Total > SubTotal`

Logic seems fine to me, but I have no idea why it's not working :(

Comment: Is it possible to have GST as a negative value or zero?

Comment: Looks like in GST and Total calculation used values _before_ you add extcost

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a record with the following values for example:

- SubTotal: 10
- GST: 0.5
- Total: 10.5

Now you execute your Update with an @extCost of 2

```
SET 
  SubTotal = SubTotal + @ExtCost, 
  GST = SubTotal * 0.05, 
  Total = SubTotal + GST
WHERE JobNumber = @JobNumber
```

During an update, the current values are taken to fill in the column values, so this is the same as

```
SET 
  SubTotal = 10 + 2, 
  GST = 10 * 0.05, 
  Total = 10 + 0.05
WHERE JobNumber = @JobNumber
```

So (subtotal) 12 >  (total) 10.05 resulting in a constraint issue.

What you want is this to take the calculated values into account, so you need to do the calculations per field.

```
SET 
  SubTotal = SubTotal + @ExtCost, 
  GST = (SubTotal + @ExtCost) * 0.05, 
  Total = (SubTotal + @ExtCost) + ((SubTotal + @ExtCost) * 0.05)
WHERE JobNumber = @JobNumber
```

or shorter

```
SET 
  SubTotal = SubTotal + @ExtCost, 
  GST = (SubTotal + @ExtCost) * 0.05, 
  Total = (SubTotal + @ExtCost) * 1.05
WHERE JobNumber = @JobNumber
```

Comment: @EricHobinYoo . . . This probably explains the issue.  This answer describes the *standard* behavior for SQL.  However, some databases do not follow this part of the standard.  How a database behaves depends on the database, which is why you need to provide the appropriate database tag.

Comment: @EricHobinYoo you triggered my interest, what databases behave different in a basic update?

Comment: . . MySQL and MariaDB do not follow the standard in this respect.  There may be others.